# Can't keep input value while trying to validate form using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a project where I have a simple registration form with name, email, phone and birthdate. I've been trying to validate the form where the user can register only if they match the requirements. I searched around a bit and gave react-hook-form a try. Basically, before applying validation, I was storing the input values in my states and I was able to keep that value when I moved on the next page using useContext. For example :

```
<input value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} type="text"
       placeholder="Name *"/>
```

When I used to only have this, I was able to type anything in the input value and it worked perfectly, but then when I changed it to this :

```
<input value={name} onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} type="text"
       placeholder="Name *" {...register("name", {required:true, minLength:2})}/>
```

Suddenly I can't type in my input anymore, when I try to, the input value doesn't change and stays the same. If I remove the value attribute from the input tag, the validation works and I can type in the input field, however, when I move to the next page using react-router, I'm assuming the state isn't holding that value anymore, which I need to pass it to a post request to send the data to the server. I'm a little confused, If anyone can provide me with some tips I'd be really grateful.